# RubyMine Waring Message - "Duplicated jQuery selector"

Tags: jquery, warnings, selector, rubymine

I have add some simple JavaScript/jQuery code to my Rails application which is making [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) to display the following warning:

```
"Duplicated jQuery selector".
```

The environment gives me additional information about the warning message:

> Checks that jQuery selectors are used in an efficient way. It suggests
>   to split descendant selectors which are prefaced with ID selector and
>   warns about duplicated selectors which could be cached.

The code itself is pretty simple and I am using it for years to check if an element is rendered, if it is not found, the element is added in the page:

```
if($('#error').length == 0) {
    $('<span class="error" id="error">'+error_message+'</span>')
            .insertAfter('#element');
}else {
   $('#error').html(error_message);
}
```

The environment is giving me the error above for the following line:

```
$('#error').length == 0
```

I have used this for a long time but google it again to see if there is a way to rewrite it, the only thing that I have found is to use just:

```
$('#error').length
```

But the environment show me the same warning again.

Is really there someway to optimized this and I am not using it correctly or the warning could be result of some internal *misunderstand* by the environment rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning has nothing in common with wrong or slow jQuery syntax of selector. I have been using the same selector in the current file and the RubyMine environment is saying that this can be optimized by making reference to this selector, as follows:

```
var selector = $(jquery_selector)
```